# Approaches for user extensible entities with a relational database (mySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, entities, entity-attribute-value

We have a php/mysql system with about 5 core entities.  We now need to add the ability for customers to create custom fields for some of these entities on a per project basis.

They would contain a label, key, type, default value, and possible allowed values.

This is so they could add a custom date field, or a custom dropdown to the UI and save this value against the specific entity.

What is the best approach for storing this kind of data in a mySQL database?  I need to store both the config for the field, and then the current value for a specific entity.

I've had a look at various options here.. https://ayende.com/blog/3498/multi-tenancy-extensible-data-model

But this is not really at a tenancy level, more a project level.

I was thinking...

- A CustomFields table to hold the configuration of a field against an entity type and project id.
- A CustomFieldValues table to hold the value saved against the field - a row per field ( entity_id | field_id | field_value)

Then we create relationships between the entities and these custom values when retrieving the entities.

The issue with this is that there will be as many rows in the Values table as there are custom fields - so saving a entity will result in X extra rows.  On top of that, these are versioned, so once a new version is created, there will be another X rows created for that new version.

Also, you can't index the fields on name, joins would become pretty complex i think as you have to join to the configuration and the values to build the key value pair to return against the entity, and how would you select based on a custom field name, when the filed name was actually a value?

I don't want to add dynamic columns to the table, as this will affect ALL the entites in the whole system - not just the ones in the current client / project.

The other option is to store the values in a JSON column.

This could be on the entity row itself `customFields` or similar.  This would prevent the extra rows per field, but also has issues with lack of indexing etc, and still need to join to the config table.  However, you could perform queries by the property name if the `key=value` was stored in the JSON... `WHERE entity.customFields->"$.myCustomFieldName" > 1`.

Storing the filed name in the json does mean you cannot change it once created, without a lot of pain.

If anyone has any advice on approaches for this, or articles to point me at that would be much appreciated - Im sure this has been solved many times before....

Answer (score 0):

JSON records:  No!  A thousand times no! If you do that, just wait until somebody actually uses your system for a few tens of millions of  records, then asks you to search on one of your extra fields.  Your support people will curse your name.

Key-value store.  Probably yes.  There's a very widely deployed existence proof of this design: WordPress. It has a table called wp_postmeta, containing metadata fields applying to wp_posts (blog pages and posts).  It's proven successful.

You will need to do some multiple joining to use this stuff.  For example, to search on height and eye-color, you'd need

```
 SELECT p.person_id, p.first, p.last, h.value height, e.value eye_color
   FROM person p
   LEFT JOIN attrib h ON p.person_id = h.person_id AND h.key='eye_color'
   LEFT JOIN attrib e ON p.person_id = e.person_id AND e.key='height'
  WHERE e.value='green' and CAST(h.value AS INT) <  160
```

As the CAST in that `WHERE` clause shows, you'll have some struggles with data type as well.

You'll need LEFT JOIN operations in this sort of attribute lookup; ordinary inner JOIN operations will suppress rows with missing attributes, and that might not work for you.

But, if you do a good job with indexes, you'll be able to get decent performance from this approach.

The table structure envisioned in my example doesn't have your table describing each additional field, but you know how to add that.  It also doesn't have explicit support for multi-project / multitenant data separation. But you can add that as well.

Comment: Well, I disagree.  Key-value sucks more than JSON.  I prefer to compromise between explicit columns (for a _few_ things) plus JSON for the arbitrary junk.  See the EAV tag for many more Q&A on this general topic.

Comment: yeah - I suppose those two answers sum up my dilemma!  Ill do some reading on the EAV posts...